# SUMIF like functions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
Date    Attribute1  Attribute2  Attribute3
6/2/2014    7   6   9
6/2/2014    10  9   7
6/2/2014    6   6   8
6/3/2014    6   9   5
6/3/2014    5   7   6
6/4/2014    9   7   5
6/5/2014    8   6   8
6/5/2014    7   10  8
```

I want to apply each column values on dates such that the output looks like the following:

```
Date    Attribute1  Attribute2  Attribute3
6/2/2014    23  21  24
6/3/2014    11  16  11
6/4/2014    9   7   5
6/5/2014    15  16  16
```

I do not know what possible methods are in Pandas to do this operation. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a combination of groupby and sum operator:

```
df.groupby('Date').sum()
Out[34]: 
          Attribute1  Attribute2  Attribute3
Date                                        
6/2/2014          23          21          24
6/3/2014          11          16          11
6/4/2014           9           7           5
6/5/2014          15          16          16
```